# How to push a JavaScript array into an array in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

The Angular component receives an array from a JavaScript file that parses a JSON and return it in an array. However, I had an issue that the component in the template doesn't recognize the variable `jsonArray:any`, it says it is undefined.

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import '../assets/js/jsonReader.js'

declare var myExtObject: any;
declare var webGlObject: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
 template: `
     <div>
        {{jsonArray.name}}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {

 test: Object[];
 jsonArray:any;
 output = [];

  constructor() {
    this.jsonArray = webGlObject.init();
  }

}
```

This is this is JavaScript code

```
var webGlObject = (function () {
  return {
    init: function () {
      getJsonArryObject();
    }
  }
})(webGlObject || {})

function getJsonArryObject() {
  loadJSON(function (response) {
    // Parse JSON string into object
    var js = JSON.parse(response);
  });

  //return getObjects(js, key, val);
}
```

And this is the JSON file

```
[
  {
    "name": "ar",
    "hasTributaryInfo": true,
    "hasTributaryInfoMandatory": false,
    "isRazonSocialMandatory": true,
    "isRUCMandatory": false,
    "array": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "sa",
    "hasTributaryInfoMandatory": true,
    "hasTributaryInfo": true,
    "isRazonSocialMandatory": true,
    "isRUCMandatory": true,
    "object": {
      "a": "b",
      "c": "d",
      "e": "f"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "co",
    "hasTributaryInfoMandatory": false,
    "hasTributaryInfo": false,
    "isRazonSocialMandatory": false,
    "isRUCMandatory": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Your init function doesn't return anything, so when you do `this.jsonArray = webGlObject.init();` you are setting this.jsonArray to undefined.

Comment: what is `loadJSON()` doing? is it a library or your own implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**: You can use Observables:

```
var webGlObject = (function () {
  return {
    init: function () {
      return getJsonArryObject();
    }
  }
})(webGlObject || {})

function getJsonArryObject() {
  let subject = new Subject();

  loadJSON(function (response) {
    // Parse JSON string into object
    var js = JSON.parse(response);
    subject.next(js);
    subject.complete();
  });

  return subject;
}
```

Then you can have:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
 template: `
     <div *ngFor="let item in jsonArray$ | async">
        {{ item.name }}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {

 jsonArray$: Observable<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.jsonArray$ = webGlObject.init();
  }
}
```

**Solution 2**: You can use Promises:

```
var webGlObject = (function () {
  return {
    init: function () {
      return getJsonArryObject();
    }
  }
})(webGlObject || {})

function getJsonArryObject() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    loadJSON(function (response) {
      // Parse JSON string into object
      var js = JSON.parse(response);
      resolve(js);
    });
  });
}
```

Then you can have:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
 template: `
     <div *ngFor="let item in jsonArray">
        {{ item.name }}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {

 jsonArray: any[] = [];

  constructor() {
    webGlObject.init().then(data => this.jsonArray = data);
  }
}
```